# Cleaning Pandas datadframes to return strings only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is almost fully processed, but I still have some data as follows:

```
None
None
[None]
[ Testy McTesterSon]
[["None"]]
[ 1234567]
```

All lists are single elements. At this point, I want my dataframe to return only strings. If `None` then just return the string `"None"`. All data will be written to a CSV. I've tried some lambda functions and to use the apply() function with little success on this last part.

All guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove trailing values:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).str.strip('[ ]"')
print (df)
                 col
0               None
1               None
2               None
3  Test yMcTesterSon
4               None
5            1234567
```

Comment: Legend! Thank you!